# Sharepoint 2010 - xlviewer.aspx - Hide "Edit in Browser"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-web-apps, editing-menu, toolbar

I have a document library where I store Excel files. The document library is configured to open documents in browser, so whenever I click on an Excel file it opens in xlviewer.aspx. Having Office Web Apps installed on top of my Sharepoint server, the button "Edit in browser" is visible in the toolbar.

I need to make this button (functionality) visible or not depending on user permissions.

I had a look at 14/TEMPLATE/LAYOUTS/XLViewer.aspx and I saw it uses an Excel Web Access webpart, but I couldn't find any option related to the edit functionality.

Do you have any suggestions on how to hide the "Edit in browser" button ?